# Codeigniter session error. I can't fix

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, server, continuous-integration

I have some problem with my app on [codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/).

When I'm visiting the site on the localhost it's fine, but when I'm copy application to the remote server I get 404 error open visiting [the site](http://szwajcar.info.pl/web1/).

this translates to :

> **An uncaught Exception was encountered**
>
> Type: Exception
>
> Message: Session: Configured save path '/home/site/14238/www/web1/system>/cache' is not writable by the PHP process.
>
> Filename: /home/site/14238/www/web1/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 124
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/site/14238/www/web1/application/controllers/Home.php
>   Line: 6
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/site/14238/www/web1/index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once
>
> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(35183c9923cab619845ef0f478fc300e62bac6b5) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/www:/home/site:/usr/share/php)
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 154
>
> Backtrace:

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fopen() [function.fopen]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(35183c9923cab619845ef0f478fc300e62bac6b5) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/www:/home/site:/usr/share/php)
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 156
>
> Backtrace:
>   
>   **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fopen(35183c9923cab619845ef0f478fc300e62bac6b5) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 156
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: HI @Przemyslaw Szlufinski, I don't know proper solution but try this once, give the write permission to all files in server. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give the writable permission to `/home/site/14238/www/web1/system/cache` directory

Answer (score -1):

Lets start fixing them one by one :)

- First make sure your webserver user has the write access to your application's cache directory

Comment: There is good chance just this change will fix all the other issues since they all seems to have same scope ;)